# Negate if condition in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, negate

I'm stuck at trying to negate the following command:

```
wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Sorry you are Offline"
        exit 1
```

This if condition returns true if I'm connected to the internet. I want it to happen the other way around but putting `!` anywhere doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where did you put it? `if ! [[ ...` works

Comment: you can also use it this way: wget your_xxxx_params || ( echo "oh oh" && exit 1)

Comment: > calling a subshell just to output an error

Comment: [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 330, accepted):

You can choose:

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then       # -ne: not equal

if ! [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then     # -eq: equal

if [[ ! $? -eq 0 ]]; then
```

`!` inverts the return of the following expression, respectively.

Comment: are the double brackets necessary? why is that?

Comment: @AlexanderMills: There are several ways to do this. With double or single brackets or with `test` command: `if test $? -ne 0; then`

Comment: This answer is unnecessary verbose. `if` expects a statement that is either 0 or 1, so you can use the command itself and invert it: `if ! wget ...; then ...; fi`

Answer (score 129):

Better

```
if ! wget -q --spider --tries=10 --timeout=20 google.com
then
  echo 'Sorry you are Offline'
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Important: keep a space between the `!` and the following command otherwise you will be doing a history expansion. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/understanding-the-exclamation-mark-in-bash

Comment: Steven why do you have only 1 reputation?

Comment: Looks like Steven has been banned - if you check out his profile it says he's suspended until autumn 2022 

Answer (score 9):

If you're feeling lazy, here's a terse method of handling conditions using `||` (or) and `&&` (and) after the operation:

```
wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com || \
{ echo "Sorry you are Offline" && exit 1; }
```

Comment: In real-life scripts you should change the `&&` after the echo command to a `;`. The reason for this is that if the output is being redirected to a file on a full disk, the `echo` will return failure and the `exit` will never fire. This is probably not the behaviour you want.

Comment: or you can use `set -e` and failing `echo` will exit the script anyway

Answer (score 8):

You can use unequal comparison `-ne` instead of `-eq`:

```
wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Sorry you are Offline"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you're comparing numbers, you can use an [arithmetic expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs), which allows for simpler handling of parameters and comparison:

```
wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
if (( $? != 0 )); then
    echo "Sorry you are Offline"
    exit 1
fi
```

Notice how instead of `-ne`, you can just use `!=`. In an arithmetic context, we don't even have to prepend `$` to parameters, i.e.,

```
var_a=1
var_b=2
(( var_a < var_b )) && echo "a is smaller"
```

works perfectly fine. This doesn't appply to the `$?` special parameter, though.

Further, since `(( ... ))` evaluates non-zero values to true, i.e., has a return status of 0 for non-zero values and a return status of 1 otherwise, we could shorten to

```
if (( $? )); then
```

but this might confuse more people than the keystrokes saved are worth.

The `(( ... ))` construct is available in Bash, but not required by the [POSIX shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) (mentioned as possible extension, though).

This all being said, it's better to avoid `$?` altogether in my opinion, as in [Cole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26475623/3266847) and [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26475880/3266847).

Comment: You sure about `(( ... ))`? [**POSIX Programmers Reference - Compound Commands**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh, I didn't find that! So it's mentioned as an extension, but not required. I'll amend.

Comment: Yes, that one always got me too. It sure makes life easier in shell though `:)`