# Condition if not general for every command

Tags: bash, if-statement

I searched for if not commands, found a lot of answer for specific commands, but if I want something for any commands, how to do it? I'd like to know if there is a way for every condition to reverse it's result... not like knowing -eq and -ne...

what I want to do is a not of this

```
while [ -z ${!specificCommands[$d]} ]
```

and a not for this

```
for (( d=1; d<=$qtyOfParamInACommand; d++ ))
```

tried

```
for (( d=1; ![d<=$qtyOfParamInACommand]; d++ ))
```

but result are not as expected

so not just normal if... this is probably simple syntax. I will appreciate the answer specific for this command, but my point is to just reverse like in C with !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Negate if condition in bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475358/negate-if-condition-in-bash-script)

Comment: does it also work the same for the while command? or in the middle of a for command?
Example, for this for, how would I make a not of the condition in the middle, syntax correct?
for (( d=1; d<=$qtyOfParamInACommand; d++ ))

Comment: Which language are we talking about?

Comment: linux, I will add it in the title

Comment: did you try with a space? `! [d<=....]`

Comment: thx a lot, I will mark the first answer as what solved the problem since it was mostly a stupid syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite of:

```
while   [ -z ${!specificCommands[$d]} ]
```

is either of these:

```
while ! [ -z ${!specificCommands[$d]} ]
while   [ -n ${!specificCommands[$d]} ]
```

Note that you also need to quote the variable, or use double brackets where quotes aren't required. If you don't, you'll run into trouble when `${!specificCommands[$d]}` is the empty string.

```
# better
while ! [ -z "${!specificCommands[$d]}" ]
while   [ -n "${!specificCommands[$d]}" ]

# best
while ! [[ -z ${!specificCommands[$d]} ]]
while   [[ -n ${!specificCommands[$d]} ]]
```

The negation of:

```
for ((d = 1; d <= qtyOfParamInACommand; d++))
```

is:

```
# note: broken
for ((d = 1; !(d <= qtyOfParamInACommand); d++))
for ((d = 1; d > qtyOfParamInACommand; d++))
```

Notice that the `$` isn't necessary inside of `((...))`.

Also, in actuality you wouldn't negate the condition, you'd flip the entire loop so it counts backwards. The loops I wrote above are actually broken. This is a more proper "opposite":

```
for ((d = qtyOfParamInACommand; d >= 1; d--))
```

Comment: thx! I just wonder, for the for, why can't the condition be between [] brackets? I would thing those [] brackets apply to enclose any kind of condition?

Comment: The brackets are a very specific command. `[` is just a (poorly chosen, IMO) synonym for the `test` command, which requires the last argument to be `]` so that it *looks* like syntax. The result is confusion for generations of shell programmers without any tangible benefit.

Comment: ah!! then I see... so if I get it, in the for, the test command is already there by default, so no need for  []