# Does the Exclamation point represent negation in Bash IF condition?

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

I've seen something along the lines of

```
if ! some-command; then
    #do something
fi
```

What's the effect of the exclamation point? I see that if you use brackets, [it can be used for negation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475358/negate-if-condition-in-bash-script).

Is that the same effect here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented in `man bash`:

> If the reserved word `!`  precedes a pipeline, the exit status of that pipeline is the  logical  negation  of  the  exit  status as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Correct.

Here is a code sample:

```
anny ~> if ! grep $USER /etc/passwd
More input> then echo "your user account is not managed locally"; fi
your user account is not managed locally

anny > echo $?
0

anny >
```

Source: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: `echo $?` will always return `0` because the exit status of the `if...then...fi` block is 0. Try it with different combination and you will see that it will always be 0 even when the `if` statement is broken, such as syntax errors.

Comment: In short, the exit status of the `if...fi` block is the exit status of the list within the block, not the exit status of the condition.