# Does it matter if exclamation point is inside or outside brackets in Bash conditionals?

Tags: bash, shell

It seems that you can write a negated conditional either as

```
if ! [[ ... ]]; then
```

or

```
if [[ ! ... ]]; then
```

Are there reasons to choose one or the other approach, assuming that the semantics of the operation are the same? (I.e., obviously, in the second version, if the `...` is a compound statement and you're not careful to group the expression properly then you may end up negating only the first part of the expression.)

Comment: See: [Negate if condition in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26475358/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for the link; the answers there explain there are equivalent forms, but do not explain _why_ one would want to choose one or the other form. So, I think the present question still has independent value.

Comment: I am also of your opinion. Therefore, I have not closed the question as a duplicate.

Comment: I saw this once [![:space:]] where it couldn't seem to make up it's mind.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it is **completely up to your own preference**. The next commands are completely equivalent:

```
if [[ $x -ne $y ]]; then
if ! [[ $x -eq $y ]]; then
if [[ ! $x -eq $y ]]; then
```

Your preferences might be based on different if conditions:

- `if [[ $x -ne $y ]]; then`: Simple comparisons without any complexity like ordinary variable comparison.
- `if ! [[ $x -eq $y ]]; then`: Suppose you have a complex if condition that might be a result of some function instead of `$x -eq $y`.
- `if [[ ! $x -eq $y ]]; then`: Unnecessary, use either first or second, depending on what type of if condition you have. I would never use this one!

Comment: Does this same reasoning apply to commands using single brackets? Thanks.

Comment: @Josh I am not sure what you mean by that. Could you provide an example please.

Comment: `if [ ! -d $dirname ]; then someaction; else otheraction; fi` vs. `if ! [ -d $dirname ]; then someaction; else otheraction; fi`. Thanks!

Comment: [This resource](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Logical_Not_!) seems to say the `!` should be inside single brackets. I'm not sure if there is consensus.

Comment: Inside the square brackets the exclamation mark becomes part of the boolean expression passed to "test" command. Outside the square brackets the exclamation mark is just another shell (possibly built-in) command that negates the exit code of the command to the right of it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367069/how-can-i-negate-the-return-value-of-a-process).