# What is wrong with this conditional statement in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, validation

I am trying to check:

if $file is a binary, and the $file is not an image file then do something.

```
if [[ "$(file --dereference --mime "$FILE")" =~ binary ]] && [[ "$FILE" != \.jpg$|\.jpeg$|\.png$ ]]; then
  echo "$1 is a binary file"
  exit 0
fi
```

The error is a `syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token`

I guess I am probably overlooking something simple. I have googled quite a bit but cannot get a working statement. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `!=` is a plain (/glob pattern) string comparison, not a regex comparison. Unfortunately, there's no negative form of `=~`, but you can always just use `[[ ! "$FILE" =~ ...` BTW, I find the regex pattern `\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$` easier to read (and equivalent).

Comment: See: [Negate if condition in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26475358/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to trying to do a negate match on the second `[[`. You can do it by putting `!` before a match `=~`

Here is an example that may help you:

```
[[ ! 'foo.png' =~ \.(jpe?g|png)$ ]] && echo not a image
```

Comment: Beware of the double negative. You test for `not an image`, so when the test succeeds, use `&&` (not `||`) before printing `echo "not an image"`